# ffmpeg concat fail with different bitrate videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg3.2.5.1 to concat some videos that have not the same bitrate.
The problem is that on the output video, there are horrible squares.
and before it was working (with ffmpeg 3.0.2)

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i /tmp/listOfVideos.txt -codec copy $DESTFILE
```

/tmp/listOfVideos.txt :

```
/test/video0.mp4
/test/video1.mp4
```

...

it seems that ffmpeg doesn't detect that there is different bitrate

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the second video had no sound.  Added a silent m4a and it concatenated fine. `ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to compile ffmpeg with the flag **--enable-libvidstab**
to have the library **[VidStab](https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab)**

This library was not present in the **backports** package.

Now, it's working fine ! (no color artifacts, no loss of quality, no scrambled images)

Comment: Since you are not using that library, it has nothing to do with the change. Likely some demuxing/muxing bug that got fixed in the new version you compiled.

Comment: I could not understand the documentation in that package and couldn't figure out where to place it. Do the VidStab directories go at the ffmpeg root?